# Cannot assign "'T Shirt for mens'": "CartProdVarient.cart_product" must be a "CartProduct" instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

**Models**

```
class CartProduct(models.Model):
    cart_product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cart_holder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_product

class CartProdVarient(models.Model):
    cart_product = models.ForeignKey(CartProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart_prod_varient = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_prod_varient
```

**Views**

```
 def add_cart(request):
    prod = Product.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('product_id'))

    CartProdVarient(cart_product=prod.product_name).save()

    return render(request, 'app/service-page.html')
```

**Problem**
i want to assign some value to "cart_product" while its a Foreign key but it giving me error..

i want something like this :

```
 CartProdVarient(cart_product="T-Shirt", cart_prod_varient="small size").save()
```

T-Shirt is already in "cart_product_name"

Comment: What is the difference between "product" and "cart product"?

Comment: Product is another Model

Comment: but it is not clear how you are modeling this. Why is `CartProduct` not pointing to a `Product`? Why is there no `ProductVariant` model with `CartProdVariant` pointing to that `ProductVariant`?

Comment: i do have other models but at this point i want to assign value to "cart_product " which is foreign key of "CartProduct".

Comment: something like this >> 
CartProdVarient(cart_product="T-Shirt", cart_prod_varient="small size").save()

Comment: well then you will first need to create a `CartProduct` object. But a potential problem is that there might already be such object there with the same name/user combination for example.

Comment: yes "CartProduct" already have  cart_product_name  = "T-Shirt"

Comment: for that specific user...?

Comment: yes, basically its cart for a specific person, he will add to cart  a product and that product also have dynamic varients. i need to add product to cart for specific person and then also want to add which varients he selected...

Comment: may be we also need to add foreign key of User to "CartProdVarient"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models are working fine. And the foreign key integration and model fields are correct. There is no error in the model.

The problem is with your views :

```
prod = Product( id = request.POST.get("product_id") )
#  this return an product object named prod , and this is a product object.
```

See your model CartProductVariant , you have defined the cart_product to be the foreignkey on the model CartProduct .

```
class CartProdVarient(models.Model):
    cart_product = models.ForeignKey(CartProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart_prod_varient = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_prod_varient
```

Your first mistake .
See your views in this line :

```
CartProdVarient(cart_product=prod.product_name).save()
```

You have defined relation with the CartProduct object but  you are providing the name of the Product object . These two are different models. This might be the first case of error .

Your second mistake .
Now see your views , in this line :

```
CartProdVarient(cart_product=prod.product_name).save()
```

You have defined the relation with the CartProduct , in Django whenever a foreign key is made the object is provided in the argument but you are providing the name of the product where as the cart_product will take the object of the CartProduct itself. It does not take the model fields , it takes the object itself.

change your code to this if the model CartProduct and Product are same :

```
CartProdVarient(cart_product=prod).save()
```

If the model CartProduct and Proudct are not same ( and I think they are not ) , you should change cart_product argument of Product object to CartProject object.

```
CartProdVarient(cart_product= CartPoduct.objects.get(id = request.POST.get("cart_product_id"))).save()
```

The whole code for the views need to be changed based on the model you have created and what is the relation you have defined on the models .

If the Product model and the CartProduct model are same ( and I don't think so they are ) . Use this code snippet .

```
def add_cart(request):
    prod = Product.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('product_id'))

    CartProdVarient(cart_product=prod).save()

    return render(request, 'app/service-page.html')
```

If they are different use this :

```
def add_cart(request):
    prod = CartProduct.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('cart_product_id'))

    CartProdVarient(cart_product=prod).save()

    return render(request, 'app/service-page.html')
```

Comment: Products and CartProduct are different but
CartProdVarient(cart_product=prod).save()
is not working it showing me the same error

Comment: if its confusing for you let me make it simple for you.
how can i set value to "cart_product" which is foreign key. cart_product=prod is not working...